# Can not set text for JTextField from another class

Tags: java, swing, button

I have ran into yet another issue. I am trying to set the text of a JTextField from another java class, and it does not seem to work.

I have tried the following:

- calling the setter from inside the GUI class to .setText with a String. WORKS!
- Setting the JTextField to some text so it isnt NULL -failed
- Calling another method inside the GUI class, pass the string, then call the setter for the JTextField to set its text to the string. -failed (Just an idea i wanted to play with)
- I did insure that the string is passed into the setter method by using a println. WORKED.

From googling around I believe that i have not set the reference to the main GUI?

Here is the GUI Class:

```
package book;

import book.BookIO;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

/**
 *
 * 
 */
public class UserInterface implements ActionListener {

    //Containers 

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Ye old Book stoppe");
    JPanel toppane = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    JPanel bottomPane = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    //Buttons
    JButton processItem = new JButton("Process Item #1");
    JButton confirmItem = new JButton("Confirm Item #1");
    JButton viewOrder = new JButton("View Order");
    JButton finishOrder = new JButton("Finish Order ");
    JButton newOrder = new JButton("New Order");
    JButton exit = new JButton("Exit");
    //TextFields
    JTextField amount = new JTextField();
    JTextField id = new JTextField();
    JTextField quantity = new JTextField();
    JTextField info = new JTextField("");
    JTextField total = new JTextField();
    //Labels
    JLabel num = new JLabel("Enter Number of Items in this Order:");
    JLabel bookID = new JLabel("Enter Book ID for Item #1:");
    JLabel quantityItem = new JLabel("Enter Quantity for Item #1:");
    JLabel itemInfo = new JLabel("Item #1:");
    JLabel subtotal = new JLabel("Order subtotal for 0 Items(s):");

    public void startUI() {

        UserInterface gui = new UserInterface();
        gui.bookingUI();

    }

    public void bookingUI() {
        //sets windows, and pane in the UI 
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        frame.setSize(800, 300);

        //adding the labels to the panel
        c.insets = new Insets(5, 0, 0, 0);
        c.gridx = 2;
        c.gridy = 1;
        toppane.add(num, c);
        c.gridx = 2;
        c.gridy = 2;
        toppane.add(bookID, c);
        c.gridx = 2;
        c.gridy = 3;
        toppane.add(quantityItem, c);
        c.gridx = 2;
        c.gridy = 4;
        toppane.add(itemInfo, c);
        c.gridx = 2;
        c.gridy = 5;
        toppane.add(subtotal, c);
        toppane.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        frame.add(toppane);

        //add textfield to panel
        c.ipadx = 400;
        c.insets = new Insets(5, 10, 0, 0);
        c.gridx = 3;
        c.gridy = 1;
        toppane.add(amount, c);
        c.gridx = 3;
        c.gridy = 2;
        toppane.add(id, c);
        c.gridx = 3;
        c.gridy = 3;
        toppane.add(quantity, c);
        c.gridx = 3;
        c.gridy = 4;
        toppane.add(info, c);
        c.gridx = 3;
        c.gridy = 5;
        toppane.add(total, c);

        //----------------------------------------------------------BUTTOM PANE-------------------------
        //adding the buttons to the pane.---------------------------------------------------------------
        GridBagConstraints b = new GridBagConstraints();
        b.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
        b.ipadx = 10;
        b.ipady = 10;
        b.gridx = 1;
        b.gridy = 0;
        bottomPane.add(processItem, b);
        processItem.addActionListener(this);
        b.gridx = 2;
        b.gridy = 0;
        bottomPane.add(confirmItem, b);
        confirmItem.setEnabled(false);
        confirmItem.addActionListener(this);
        b.gridx = 3;
        b.gridy = 0;
        bottomPane.add(viewOrder, b);
        viewOrder.setEnabled(true);
        viewOrder.addActionListener(this);
        b.gridx = 4;
        b.gridy = 0;
        bottomPane.add(finishOrder, b);
        finishOrder.setEnabled(true);
        finishOrder.addActionListener(this);
        b.gridx = 5;
        b.gridy = 0;
        bottomPane.add(newOrder, b);
        newOrder.addActionListener(this);
        b.gridx = 6;
        b.gridy = 0;
        bottomPane.add(exit, b);
        exit.addActionListener(this);
        bottomPane.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        frame.add(bottomPane, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.setSize(810, 310);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    //action listener for the buttons 
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        if (e.getSource() == processItem) {
            confirmItem.setEnabled(true);
            processItem.setEnabled(false);
            BookIO findInfo = new BookIO();
            findInfo.readFile(id.getText());

        } else if (e.getSource() == confirmItem) {
            processItem.setEnabled(true);
            confirmItem.setEnabled(false);
        } else if (e.getSource() == viewOrder) {

        } else if (e.getSource() == finishOrder) {

        } else if (e.getSource() == newOrder) {

        } else if (e.getSource() == exit) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

//Creating getters and setters to change the text for the buttons and labels, as well as getting text from the textfields.
    public void setProcessItemBtn(int num) {
        processItem.setText("Process Item #" + num);
        processItem.validate();
        processItem.repaint();
    }

    public void setConfirmItemBtn(int num) {
        confirmItem.setText("Confirm Item #" + num);
        confirmItem.validate();
        confirmItem.repaint();
    }

    public void setViewOrderBtn(String title) {

        viewOrder.validate();
        viewOrder.repaint();
    }

    public void setInfo(String title) {
        System.out.println(title);
        info.setText(title);
        info.validate();
        info.repaint();
    }

    public String getAmount() {
        String str = amount.getText();
        return str;
    }
}
```

Here is the class with the method call to the setter:

```
package book;

import book.UserInterface;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

/**
 *
 * 
 */
public class BookIO {

    public void readFile(String bookID) {

        try {

            FileReader read = new FileReader("inventory.txt");
            BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(read);
            StringBuffer stringBuff = new StringBuffer();
            String line, delim = "[,]";
            for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
                line = buffer.readLine();
                String[] tokens = line.split(delim);

                if ((Objects.equals(tokens[0], bookID)) == true) {
                    UserInterface setInfo = new UserInterface();
                    setInfo.setInfo(tokens[1]);
                }
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error starting file!");
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is that you are instantiating a new `UserInterface` object which is wrong:

```
UserInterface setInfo = new UserInterface();
setInfo.setInfo(tokens[1]);
```

Your `readFile()` from `BookIO` should be like this:

```
public static void readFile(String bookID, UserInterface userInterface) {
        try {

            FileReader read = new FileReader("inventory.txt");
            BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(read);
            StringBuffer stringBuff = new StringBuffer();
            String line, delim = "[,]";
            for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
                line = buffer.readLine();
                String[] tokens = line.split(delim);

                if ((Objects.equals(tokens[0], bookID)) == true) {
                    userInterface.setInfo(tokens[1]);
                }
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error starting file!");
        }
    }
```

In your `UserInterface` class, where you have this:

```
BookIO findInfo = new BookIO();
findInfo.readFile(id.getText());
```

Change the lines to this:

```
//pass the already created userInterface object.
BookIO.readFile(id.getText(), this);
```

Note: I have tested this and it worked. Tell me if it doesn't work for you.

Comment: Thank you. It works. I could not use the 'BookIO.readFile(id.getText, this)' because of static method issues, But i retained the created instance, but passed the USerInterface class and it worked!

Comment: Well if you look at the method definition, you will see that I have also changed it to static. Sorry I was in such a hurry I forgot to explain why I have done that. Anyway, I always make utility methods static and I think of the readFile method as utility. Although some may say that I am wrong since objects were created.

Answer (score 1):

You always make a new `UserInterface` instance

```
UserInterface setInfo = new UserInterface();
setInfo.setInfo(tokens[1]);
```

That sounds incorrect. Normally you would only have one such unstance (the visible one), and update that one.

Small side-note

```
if( Objects.equals(tokens[0], bookID)) == true )
```

can be simplified to

```
if( Objects.equals(tokens[0], bookID)) )
```

Comment: I moved the instance  so it is only created once. It still did not work, but i also tested to see if the string was passed to the setter method and it was. haha Thanks for the tip!